# TFS connection error (TF31001)

Tags: tfs

I have been using a TFS Server for 8 months. It was working well yesterday. Today, I can't connect this server. Please see the connection error below.

> TF31001: Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server at server-pc. The
>   server returned the following error: Please contact your
>   administrator. There was an error contacting the server. Technical
>   information(for administrator): HTTP code 500: Internal Server Error

I checked the TFS server, it is online. And I have restarted the TFS applicaton on IIS. Then I clean all cache of TFS server. Until now, I can't connect the TFS server and it shows the previous message. How can I fix it? Thanks all

Comment: Check the event log for the actual error.

Comment: It shows about TFSJobAgent process. But I don't know why.

Comment: I mean: read the event log entries to discover the actual error. "About TFSJobAgent" isn't anywhere near specific enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing your cache on your laptop. Here:

C:\Users\asdasdas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0

5.0 is vs2013, 4.0 is 2012 etc.

Comment: the cache on your laptop?

Comment: clearing cache under local did not help. still getting the same error